# SQL counting and multiple subqueries on huge tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few SQL tables, named FOS, keywords, and PRef. Their structure and relationships are as follow:

```
+------------------+      +------------------+      +-----------------+
|       FOS        |      |     keywords     |      |       PRef      |
+------------------+      +------------------+      +-----------------+
|fosID (PK)        |--+   |pkID (PK)         |  +---|pID1 (PK)        |
|fosName           |  +---|fosID(FK)         |  +---|pID2 (PK)        |
+------------------+      |paperID (FK)      |--+   +-----------------+
 ( 53k+ rows)             +------------------+       ( 952M+ rows)
                           ( 157M+ rows)
```

Currently i can do it by supplying a single fosID to my query, but since the fos table contains over 1k records, i do not have enough manpower to manually feed every fosID and get its corresponding rowCount then merging all results

```
declare @fosID varchar(10)='1234567890';--my fosID

select fos.fosID,fos.fosName,count(*) as rowCount 
from  PRef pr left join FOS fos on fos.fosID=@fosID 
where 
     pr.pID1 in(SELECT paperID FROM keywords k where k.fosID=@fosID)
  OR pr.pID2 in(SELECT paperID FROM keywords k where k.fosID=@fosID)
group by fos.fosID,fos.fosName
```

Then it gives a correct result as:

```
+----------+--------+----------+
|fosID     |fosName |rowCount  |
+----------+--------+----------+
|1234567890|name1   |34        |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

Now i want to get a list of all fos items and number of records in PRef for EACH of the 53k+ fos item.

I've tried to modified the part in `where k.fosID=@fieldID` to `where k.fosID in (select fosID from FOS)` but less count was produced.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

P.S. I am looking at cursors right now but the performance is really...really slow

Edit 1: Expected results:

```
+----------+--------+----------+
|fosID     |fosName |rowCount  |
+----------+--------+----------+
|1234567890|name1   |34        |
|1234567891|name2   |3         |
|1234567892|name3   |23        |
|.....     |....    |...       | 
+----------+--------+----------+
 (exact same number of rows as table FOS)
```

Comment: just to be clear, are you looking to count the rows of `PRef` table that either `pID1` or `pID2` contain `fosID` ?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: i am counting number of rows in table `PRef` that either its column `pID1` or/and `pID2` is mapped to table `fosID` through table `keywords`

Comment: Please use cursors only as absolute last solution. Always try to solve queries with sql statements first.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this will give you what you want.
`SELECT fos.fosID, fos.fosName, k.rowcount
FROM FOS fos 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT fosID, COUNT(*) rowcount
  FROM keywords k
   INNER JOIN PRef pr
   ON k.paperID IN (pr.pID1, pr.pID2)
  GROUP BY fosID
 ) keywords k
 ON fos.fosID = k.fosID`

Comment: Please check your code when asking questions. You declare `@fosID` and use `@fieldID`. Also your join looks seriously dodgy `left join FOS fos on fos.fosID=@fieldID`. It's more appropriate as a filter condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just modify your subqueries to use correlated subqueries

```
select fos.fosID, fos.fosName, count(*) as rowCount 
from  PRef pr cross join
      FOS fos
where pr.pID1 in (SELECT paperID FROM keywords k where k.fosID = fos.fosID) OR
      pr.pID2 in (SELECT paperID FROM keywords k where k.fosID = fos.fosID)
group by fos.fosID, fos.fosName;
```

My guess is that the performance would be pretty bad.

Here is one alternative:

```
select fos.*, kp.cnt
from fos outer apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from keywords k join
           pref pr
           on k.paperID in (pr.pID1, pf.pID2) and
              k.fosID = fos.fosID
     ) kp;
```

I imagine that this will also have pretty bad performance characteristics.

If you can do each id separately, then the SQL Server should be able to come up with a better execution plan:

```
select fos.*, (kp1.cnt + kp2.cnt)
from fos outer apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from keywords k join
           pref pr
           on k.paperID = pr.pID1 and
              k.fosID = fos.fosID
     ) kp1 outer apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from keywords k join
           pref pr
           on k.paperID = pr.pID2 and
              k.fosID = fos.fosID
     ) kp2;
```

Answer (score 2):

First I suspect you could gain significant improvement by checking the data types in your tables. It looks like you're using varchar(10) with only numeric digits?
That sort of absurdity goes unnoticed on small tables, but on 900M rows can waste in excess of 5GB, affecting storage, memory and performance.

Second `FOS` is only really used to lookup `fosName` and at 53k rows is the smaller part of the work. So start by getting your counts per fosID correct; then join for the names.

```
;with CountPerFos as (
    SELECT  k.fosID, COUNT(*) AS fosCount
    FROM    PRef r
            INNER JOIN keywords k ON
                r.PID1 = k.paperID
             OR r.PID2 = k.paperID
    GROUP BY k.fosID
)
SELECT  c.fosID, f.fosName,
        --Need to handle fosIDs missing from CTE above
        COALESCE(c.fosCount, 0)
FROM    FOS f
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CountPerFos c
            f.fosID = c.fosID
```